# How can you tell if a GitHub pull request has been released?

Tags: github

It's fairly common to come across pull requests when searching for issues. But what has eluded me for awhile is how to determine (reliably) if/when that pull request has been released. Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'released'?  Once a pull request has been merged into master, it will be closed.

Comment: By released I mean included within a release of the product. So likely that means being incorporated into master. However, just because it's in master, doesn't mean it's been released yet. Does that clarify?

Comment: In that case, the easiest thing to do is to look in the project's CHANGELOG or release notes; git doesn't have much to do with releases _unless_ a project is tagging their releases. If a project is tagging their releases in git, then you could probably look for the first tag created from master after the pull request was merged.

Comment: @KurtRaschke so really no reliable way unless the project is following good dev practices...

Answer (score 9):

On the page of a merged pull request, scroll down until you find the merge commit. It looks like this:
[image: Merge commit in pull request history.]

Click the commit ID to arrive at the page of the commit. At the top of this page you can find which tags* in the repository that include this commit! :) It looks like this:
[image: Top box of commit page.]

* It may be that this only works for tags that are actual GitHub releases, I'm not sure how separated the two are.

Answer (score 5):

I also very frequently have this need.
I'm doing like this:

- get the id from the most recent commit in the pull request on github
- clone the repository locally
- run `git tag --contains [commit_id]`

But it would be wonderful if github provided an easier way !

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standardized way. Many well organized projects use tags for this purpose (i.e. https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tags) which designate which commit corresponds to which release